# PHPunit command not found after installing using composer

Tags: php, phpunit

I have added the PHPUnit dependency in the `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
  "php-ds/php-ds": "v1.2.0",
  "phpunit/phpunit": "v7.5.16"
}
```

and ran composer update as I have `php-ds` installed already.

This installed the PHPUnit in the vendor directory, but when I check `phpunit` in command line it says:

> phpunit command not found

Comment: how did you type the command? you are installing phpunit using composer, so you need to type the absolute path of `phpunit` executable file to the command line, i.e: `[yourprojectdir]/vendor/bin/phpunit testfile.php`

Comment: also you are placeing phpunit to `"require"` section which will install phpunit in production mode, it is recommend to put dependencies which you only need during development mode inside `"required-dev"` section, make your project cleaner and lighter.

Comment: Thanks, I accessed it as /vendor/bin/phpunit and it worked. Also, as advised i have changed to use in require-dev.

Answer (score 12):

When you run `$ phpunit` on the command-line (e.g. bash), the system will look for `phpunit` using the `PATH` variable, from the bash docs:

```
PATH   The search path for commands.  It is a colon-separated list of directories in which the shell
      looks for commands (see COMMAND EXECUTION below).  A zero-length (null) directory name in the
      value of PATH indicates the current directory.  A null directory name may appear as two adja‐
      cent  colons,  or as an initial or trailing colon.  The default path is system-dependent, and
      is set by the administrator who installs bash.  A common value is ``/usr/local/bin:
      /usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin''.
```

You can bypass search using the `PATH` variable by using an absolute path:

```
$ /absolute/path/to/vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Or a relative path (the stop character (`.`) means the current directory):

```
$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

You actually omit the stop slash part: `$ vendor/bin/phpunit`.

To avoid having to type the path you can use a bash alias (if you're using bash):

```
$ alias phpunit='./vendor/bin/phpunit'
```

Or to save typing:

```
$ alias p='./vendor/bin/phpunit'
```

See [How do I create a permanent bash alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias) for more information on aliases.